# Как узнать системные требования ПО разрабатываемого в Delphi?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe3

Можно ли в Delphi XE3 точно узнать какие характеристики системы должны быть для разрабатываемого ПО? Например, версия фреймворка.

P.S. Разработчик сам должен знать какие компоненты он использует. Но часто бывает так, что запускаешь программу на другом компьютере, а там целая гора ошибок вылезает ("компонент ... не найден", "текущая версия net framework не поддерживается" и т.п.).

Comment: какого фреймворка?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Вы путаете с .Net приложениями (C# и т.п.). Именно для них важно наличие предустановленных фреймворков.

Для приложений, разрабатываемых на Delphi, C++ (и других, генерирующих нативный код) важны только технические характеристики компьютера (например - вы планируете обрабатывать терабайтные файлы - важен винчестер) и операционной системы (для XE3 минимумом считается XP SP2).

В остальном - требуйте то, что используете. Работаете с MS Excel или 1С - естественно нужны они. Берете данные с сайта - нужен интернет. И так далее. 
Естественно, что если вы используете какую-либо .Net библиотеку - необходимо в тех.требования к своему приложению включить как минимум наличие .Net определенной версии.

P.S. Дополнительным условием по отсутствию зависимостей для программных продуктов, разрабатываемых на платформе Delphi и C++ Builder стоит считать сборку проекта без включенной опции Build with runtime packages. Если эта опция будет включена - то размер исполняемого файла станет значительно меньше, но приложению для запуска [потребуются дополнительные файлы](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Deciding_Which_Runtime_Packages_to_Use). Как минимум это rtlXXX.bpl и vclXXX.bpl.